# Connecting a Xamarin.form with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It is the first mobile application that I have worked on.

I created the database from (New Items - data - services-based database).

How to connect the data with the app, and **what file should I put connection string**? and is it in separate file one for IOS, and one for Andriod?

Second question:

When I create the database it looks like this:

[image: my database that I created]

But when I search about connecting I found something like this >>>

```
namespace XamarinSQL.Clases
{
    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Password{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is the relationship between two ways and how can I keep up with between them?

Comment: DO NOT connect directly to SQL server from a mobile app.  This is a horrible security risk.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: You are using Entity when you are connecting a datasource.  Entity automatically creates a connection string in the in the project configuration as well as a mapping file and c# classes for the database so there is not need to create a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an API server that interacts with SQL server and mobile app should consume the REST APIs

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/)